# enabling/disabling a JFrame after hiding another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have this 2 JFrame classes:

```
   public class Frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      private JButton button1;
      button1 = new JButton("Open Frame2");
      private void button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
      this.setEnabled(false);  // disable Frame1 until Frame2 is showing              
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Frame2 obj2 = new Frame2 ();
                obj2.setVisible(true); 
            }
        });
      }
    }


 public class Frame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
      public Frame2 () {
      this.setVisible(false);
      }
   Frame1 obj1 = new Frame1 ();
   private JButton button2;
      button2 = new JButton("Hide Frame2 and go to Frame1");
      private void button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
           this.setVisible(false);
      }
    }
```

As you can see, when I click on `button1` `Frame1` gets disabled and `Frame2 obj2` is created.

1. First of all I'd to know whether what I have done is a correct way to disable/defocus one parent `JFrame` to show another on top with focus.
2. And then I just need to enable `Frame1` after hiding `Frame2`, something like `obj1.setEnabled(true)`. How can I do that?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  (Make one frame a modal dialog, or just use a `CardLayout`).

Comment: ok thanks, I change Frame2 to "public class Dialog2 extends javax.swing.JDialog {}" now how can I reach my aim? And how can I make Dialog2 child of Frame1 parent?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that reflects your understanding of [*How to Make Dialogs*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

All what you have to do is to create an ref of your first class frame right inside it:

```
public 1_class_name obj;
//call the second class method getobj(o)
getobj(obj);
```

and then create a method and a ref in the second class frame:

```
1_class_name a;
public void getobj(1_class_name o){
    a=o;
}
```

After you do that, you create a listener in the second class frame:

```
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            a.setEnabled(true);
            dispose();
        }
    };
    addWindowListener(exitListener);
```

It worked for me, I hope it will work for you too ;)